# Upgrade to Rails 4 led to rspec output hanging

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

I've upgraded to Rails 4.0.0 from Rails 3.2.13. I fixed all the deprecation warnings (except for secret_base_key), upgraded database_cleaner, rspec, rspec-rails, capybara, selenium-webdriver and poltergeist to the latest versions.

Now, when I run my specs, through rake or rspec, the output of rspec eventually hangs, always on a feature test (a javascript one). The output of test.log is clear: the tests are still running, but the console is not getting any updates.

I am using:

- phantomjs 1.9.2.
- poltergeist 1.4.1

Thoughts on how I can get my test suite to behave normally again?

Comment: sure, that you did not leave any debugger, pry or sleep statements in the code?

Comment: I just checked. There are a few sleep statements, but they are a few seconds at worst.

Comment: is it possible to narrow it down to some tests?

Comment: It hangs on any of six feature tests, all of them "js: true".

Comment: might be some problem with your javascript drivers. did you try re-installing them? what do you use? selenium or some headless driver?

Comment: I am using poltergeist, a gem that leverages phantomjs.

Comment: yeah, i know that and used it successfully with rails4. are you using the latest phantomjs build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, but with capybara-webkit.

I found the solution here: [webkit_server hangs periodically when run from Capybara in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558777/webkit-server-hangs-periodically-when-run-from-capybara-in-ruby)

```
# Gemfile
group :test do
  gem 'thin'
end

# spec_helper.rb
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
Capybara.server do |app, port|
  require 'rack/handler/thin'
  Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => port)
end
```

Comment: great solution.. have you found a way to silence the test startup though? I'm now getting Thin noise http://d.pr/i/N7dh

Comment: No, I also get the noise inside my spec output. Mine is not as visible, as I run rspec with "-f doc" parameter (see what that means here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/command-line/format-option#documentation-format)